# Why does this C function produce a Question Mark

Tags: c

In this program to convert a positive integer to another base, if I put in seemingly harmless numbers, the conversion of my number into base `123` results in a question mark. Any ideas as to why this happens? I will post

```
int main(void){
    const char baseDigits[16] = {
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
        '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', };
    int convertedNumber [64];
    long int numberToConvert;
    int nextDigit, base, index = 0;

    //Get the number and base

    printf("Number to be converted? ");
    scanf ("%ld", &numberToConvert);
    printf("Base? ");
    scanf("%i", &base);

    //convert to the indicated base
    
    do {
        convertedNumber[index]=numberToConvert % base;
        ++index;
        numberToConvert = numberToConvert / base;
    }
    while (numberToConvert != 0);
    
    
    //display the results in reverse order

    printf("Converted Number = ");
    for (--index; index >=0; --index){
        nextDigit = convertedNumber[index];
        printf("%c", baseDigits[nextDigit]);
    }
    
    printf("\n"); 

    return 0;
}
```

terminal output

```
Number to be converted? 3513
Base? 123
Converted Number
=?
```

Comment: This doesn't work because in base 123, most of the digits don't correspond to printable digit characters in ASCII!  In base 123, your input number 3513 is [28] [69].  But 28 and 69 don't have ordinary digit representations.

Comment: You have put 16 digits in your `baseDigits` array. Base 123 numbers use 123 different digits. Where do you expect the other 107 digits to come from?

Comment: Basedigits should contain (base) char. That is 123 chars for base 123. What happens here is that you read outside basedigit which leads to «undefined behavior»

Comment: There's no particularly good way to print numbers in bases greater than 36. You could just use `printf("[%d]", nextDigit);`.

Comment: Or you could stick to converting numbers like 15378 or 1891498 or 232654259. :-)

Comment: Please provide the expected output for the sample input. Currently your question reads like "I use an index of up to 122 into a 16 entry array and am surprised by what happens."

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a specific application for this, or is this an assignment or exercise of some sort? The solution may depend on the goal, if there is a specific series of characters you need to use. Beyond that, as already stated, there aren't 123 printable characters in the standard ASCII character set, which makes assigning 123 unique printable characters a problem unless you use a larger character set with `wchar_t`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `baseDigits` array only has 16 digits, so only supports up to base 16.  If you use a larger base, when you go to print a digit, the expression `baseDigit[nextDigit]` will access off the end of the array whenever nextDigit >= 16.  This gives undefined behavior, but will generally just read whatever byte happens to be in memory in that spot after the end of the array.